# How to make faster MongoDB aggregations?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I am running following aggregation with the result of almost 90 seconds:

```
Rack.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                location
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$boxes"
        },
        { $project : { "reads" : "$boxes.reads", rackid: 1, "box": "$boxes.session"}},
        { $unwind : "$reads" },
        {$project: {epc: { $objectToArray: "$reads" }, rackid: 1, box: 1}},
        { $unwind : "$epc" },
        {$group: {_id:  {$substr: ["$epc.k", 0, 13]}, "total": {"$sum": {"$size": "$epc.v"}}, count: {$sum: 1}, racks: { $push: {"rack": "$rackid", "box": "$box"}}}},
        { $lookup : {from: "inventories", localField: "_id", foreignField: "barcode", as: "Details"} }
    ]);
```

My in inventories collection consist of 40000 records and I suspect this might be main reason that query gets too slow. Could you please suggest if I can make any improvements in my query or any other approach, maybe memoization? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here is:

Put an index on: `location`, `_id` and `barcode` so it should increase your search speed.

You can do it either with mongodb Compass or you do it programatically:

```
db.inventories.createIndex({ barcode: 1 });
db.racks.createIndex({ location: 1 });
```

`_id` have by default an index.

Other solution could be to install an redis server and to implement an memoization